# A word for a (prominent?) feature of something

Tags: word-request

Suppose you can distinguish something and guess its purpose just by looking at  some ???? in it.

something like prominent points (marks), marking points, or outstanding points....

My sentence is:

> Anchors serve as starting points of a data region or **marking / indexing/ featuring** points within a block of data.

It is supposed to be used for some phrases within a webpage which indicate the content of the web page

Comment: Featuring wouldn't work, as that is only a verb for "to feature" (the others can be nouns). In the context of data and that sentence, I suggest "identification" or "labels" (no "points" for labels). Marking or indexing would work but they have some other implications in this context you might want to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could describe them as:

- [**reference points**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/reference+point): "a prominent, easily located point in the terrain"
- [**markers**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/marker): "a visual or electronic aid used to mark a designated point"
- [**earmarks**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/earmark):  "any identifying or distinguishing mark or characteristic"